# Sorting arrays within an array in PHP by datetime

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, sorting

I currently have a problem within PHP where I want to sort these posts by their creation date so that they can then be shown in descending order. I have been looking for a PHP function to do this but have had no luck.

Is there an easy solution to this? Any idea will be greatly appreciated :)

```
array
      0 => 
        array
          'post_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'user_id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'post' => string 'this is a post' (length=14)
          'created' => string '2012-04-05 20:11:38' (length=19)
     1 => 
        array
          'post_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'user_id' => string '2' (length=1)
          'post' => string 'this is a post' (length=14)
          'created' => string '2012-04-05 20:11:38' (length=19)
     2 => 
        array
          'post_id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'user_id' => string '5' (length=1)
          'post' => string 'this is a post' (length=14)
          'created' => string '2012-04-05 20:11:38' (length=19)
```

Comment: Is this coming from a database? If not, why not?

Comment: from where is this array being loaded?

Comment: Yep, looks suspiciously like MySQL query rows. `ORDER BY created DESC`

Comment: It is coming from a database but because i have to grab the posts of each user seperately im trying to combine it... is there a better way of doing something like .... WHERE user_id = array(2,3,5) in MySQL?

Comment: That's hard to say if we can't see your query. `WHERE user_id IN (2,3,5)` is valid in MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$a=array(
      0 => 
        array(
          'post_id' => '1',
          'user_id' => '3',
          'post' => 'this is a post',
          'created' => '2012-04-05 20:11:40'
          ),
     1 => 
        array(
          'post_id' => '2',
          'user_id' => '2',
          'post' => 'this is a post',
          'created' => '2012-04-05 20:11:39'
          ),
     2 => 
        array(
          'post_id' => '3',
          'user_id' => '5',
          'post' => 'this is a post',
          'created' => '2012-04-05 20:11:38'
          )
);
function cmp($a,$b){
    return strtotime($a['created'])<strtotime($b['created'])?1:-1;
};

uasort($a,'cmp');
print_r($a);
?>
```

Comment: `cmp()` should return a negative value if `$a` is considered smaller than `$b`, a positive value if `$a` is greater than `$b` and 0 if they are equal.

Comment: There is no need for `strtotime`. The format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (24 hours) just needs the `strcmp` function for sorting.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting array of records/assoc_arrays by specified mysql datetime field and by order:

```
    function build_sorter($key, $dir='ASC') {
        return function ($a, $b) use ($key, $dir) {
            $t1=strtotime(is_array($a)?$a[$key]:$a->$key);
            $t2=strtotime(is_array($b)?$b[$key]:$b->$key);
            if($t1==$t2) return 0;
            return (str_to_upper($dir)=='ASC'?($t1 < $t2):($t1 > $t2)) ? -1 : 1;
        };
    }


    // $sort - key or property name 
    // $dir - ASC/DESC sort order or empty
    usort($arr, build_sorter($sort, $dir));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strtotime()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert the timestamp to an integer.

Comment: And how's that going to help sort the 2D array?

Comment: Heh ok, vague question. I thought OP was implying his stamps were Y-d-m.

Comment: If the dates are in `Y-d-m` format, you can't easily convert them to timestamps. And if they are in `Y-m-d` format, you don't need to convert them.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort an array using a custom sort function, like so:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if($a['created'] < $b['created']) {
        return 1;
    } else if ($a['created'] > $b['created']) {
        return -1;
    } else  {
        // The only option left is that they are equal
        return 0;
    }
}

usort($array, cmp);
```

For more information about usort, check the [php manpage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: This will produce an ascending order rather than descending.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function which allows you to sort an array based on your own criteria.

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['created'] == $b['created']) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a['created'] < $b['created']) ? 1 : -1;
}

usort($myArray, "cmp");

print_r($myArray);
```

Or if you want to convert to a time:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['created'] == $b['created']) {
        return 0;
    }

    $aInt = strtotime($a['created']);
    $bInt = strtotime($b['created']);

    return ($aInt < $bInt) ? 1 : -1;
}
```